# sending Paypal payment call returning 400 malformed request error

Tags: php, json, curl, paypal

I am trying to create a paypal payment using php.  I keep getting a 400 malformed request error.  I believe my problem is with the following string:

```
$postData ='
{
    "intent": "sale"
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": ' . $url_success .',
        "cancel_url": ' . $url_cancel .'
    },
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "transactions": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "total": "' . $saleTotal .'",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "description": "Test payment."
        }
    ]
}
';
```

I am then sending the string using cURL in the following line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

Here is my string printed out:

```
{ "intent": "sale" "redirect_urls": { "return_url": 
"http://localhost/~user/test/controller/PayPalTestView.php", "cancel_url": 
"http://localhost/~user/test/controller/CancelTestView.php" }, "payer": { 
"payment_method": "paypal" }, "transactions": [ { "amount": { "total": "8.31782", 
"currency": "USD" }, "description": "Test payment." } ] }
```

Here is the response I get:

```
{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"The request JSON is not well 
formed.","information_link":
"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST",
"debug_id":"7d56ae815e584"}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is in $postData, although I have no idea what's wrong.  I tried following this example: [Paypal REST API Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548854/paypal-rest-api-bad-request), but it still isn't working.  My problem is similar to that example in that I am sending and receiving the authentication token successfully.  My problem is just when trying to send the payment API call. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: You are missing a `,` after `"intent": "sale"`. Also, you should not be manually creating json arrays. Build the array in php and then use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: That did the trick. I am now building the array in php and using json_encode().  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem before. What I did is put the data first in array:

```
$data = array(  "intent"=>"sale", 
            "redirect_urls"=>array(
                "return_url"=>"<return site>", 
                "cancel_url"=>"<cancel site>"
            ),
            "payer"=>array(
                "payment_method"=>"paypal"
            ),
            "transactions"=>array(
                array(
                    "amount"=>array(
                        "total"=>"7.47",
                        "currency"=>"USD"
                    ),
                    "description"=>"This is the payment transaction description."
                )
            )
        );
```

and the http header:

```
$header = array(
"Content-Type:application/json",
"Authorization:Bearer <token here>"
```

);

then on the postfield, encode your data using json_encode:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```

I hope this will help.